# Powershell: Import-CSV , delimiter and split combined - how?

Tags: powershell, split, import-csv

**Objective:** Traverse a directory containing sub-dirs with log files, using Powershell to list hostnames in a column in the logfiles in Syslog RFC 5424 IETF formatting.
**Output:** List of hosts, their IP and timestamps of log lines

Format in the logfiles is: `col1 TAB col2 TAB col3 TAB col4 TAB col5 TAB col6`

`col6` contains various items, separated by a single SPACE and I'm after the hostname (in the example: `MyHost01`).

So far below example gives me a lot of lines like this:

```
2020-12-14 16:16:13 User.Notice  10.100.210.60 1 2020-12-14T16:17:44.755522+00:00 MyHost01 - - - [NXLOG@14506 EventReceivedTime="2020-12-14 16:17:43" SourceModuleName="auditlog" SourceModule...
```

```
# Example - yields timestamp, info, IP address and raw message
$filelist = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path D:\Logs -Include *.txt
foreach ($textfile in $filelist) {
    $filepath = $textfile.fullname
    Import-Csv $filepath -Delimiter "`t" -Header col1,col3,col4,col6 |  Format-Table col1,col3,col4,col6
}
```

To achieve my objective, I need to split `col6` by SPACE. How can this be done within my script?

Comment: Have you tried [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.1) operator?

Comment: @zett42 yes but how to build it into the script?

Comment: If you are using NXLog then perhaps you should consider using another format instead of Syslog RFC 5424 IETF that does not need such parsing horror. JSON, plain CSV, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see the TABs in your sample data. Assuming the host name is the first sub string of column 6:

```
Import-Csv $filepath -Delimiter "`t" -Header col1,col3,col4,col6 | 
    Select-Object col1, col3, col4, @{ n = 'col6'; e = { ( $_.col6 -split ' ' )[0] } } |
    Format-Table
```

[`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1) is used to to pass through columns 1, 3 and 4. Column 6 is defined as a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1) by using a hashtable, which is short form of:

```
@{ 
    name = 'col6'                                # Name of the output column 
    expression = { ( $_.col6 -split ' ' )[0] }   # Calculated value
}
```

In the expression the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.1) operator is used to split the original value of column 6 by space, which returns an array of sub strings. The first element of this array will be the value to use for column 6. Change the index `[0]` to something else if you need to extract another sub string.

Comment: actually it was the 3rd substring - works like a charm, thanks :)